# I am trying to create an NSArray for my labels

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, label

I am trying to create an NSArray for my labels but I am not sure how I am a beginner in objective c. I'm reading a text file and each question in there has four different answers options, how can I create an array to loop through my answers and display them as labels?

This how a set my txt file:
what output does this while loop generate?

```
x = 6;
while (x > 0)
{
  System.out.println(x + ", ");
  x--;
} # a. no output is generated. # b. 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, # c. 5 , 4, 3 ,2, 1. # d. the output is infinite. # b. 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, @
```

the # sign is to separate the answers and the last option is the correct answer. The @ sign is a line break.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That looks like Java, certainly not Objective-C.

Comment: @rmaddy I think that's the Java code that generates the text file he's trying to parse in Objective C

Comment: That's the text file to parse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One quick way would be using

```
NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@"#"];
```

Ignore the first object since it will contain, the question, and trim whitespaces and the @ in the last object.
This assuming there are no # in the string except to separate answers